# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined after putting the line in setTimeout

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I checked the console in the browser very carefully.
This line:

```
document.getElementById("role_show_" + $(this).attr("id").substring(7, 9)).style.display = "block";
```

is executed normally. But when I put it in a `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("role_show_" + $(this).attr("id").substring(7, 9)).style.display = "block";
}, 400);
```

The console displays this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined`

What is going on here? I am sure that all the other lines of code are unedited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` function made your `$(this)` to be in a different scope than you want it to be.
To make it work, save your `$(this)` to an variable before you call setTimeout function.

```
var that = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("role_show_" + $(this).attr("id").substring(7, 9)).style.display = "block";
}, 400);
```

So now you can access your `$(this)` in `setTimeout` function by using `that` basically.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the `$(this)`. When you are inside the function, you access the function itself, and the function does not have an `id` attribute